# I can't find error ? TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

Using the following code, the result was displayed successfully.

```
window.onload = setInterval(func_name, 5000);

function func_name() {
    var ids = document.getElementById('aa').value;
    ids_array = ids.split(',');
    for (var i in ids_array) {
        if (document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i])) {
            document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i]).innerHTML = ids_array[i];
```

However, when I used an AJAX request instead, I get the error: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`.

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i]).innerHTML = xmlhttp.response; // error is here... TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo baseurl . 'notification.php';?>?users_id=" + ids_array[i], true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
}
}
```

i am beginner, sorry for this type of code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, whether you are a beginning to coding or not, please take more time to format your code and question properly next time. This time, several members of the community have stepped in to clear it up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are sevelral problems with your code. First, there is an extra `}` at the end. Also, `window.onload = setInterval(func_name, 5000);` should be:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(func_name, 5000);
}
```

Then, `for (var i in ids_array)` should be

```
for(var i=0; i<ids_array.length; i++) { ...
```

This could be part of your problem. For several reasons, [your current loop may not work as you'd expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Finally, Ajax is asynchronous. The function you assign to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` will only run after the loop has finished, and the value of `i` will be the last value in the array (in your current code), or the length of the array (in the new version I proposed). The shortest fix looks like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = (function(i) {
    return function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i]).innerHTML = xmlhttp.response; // error is here... TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
        }
    }
}(i));
```

More explanation about why can be found at [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

---

**I realized one more thing**: to fire multiple requests like that, you need multiple XMLHttpRequest objects. I suggest using a separate function to start the ajax requests, like this:

```
function func_name() {
    var ids = document.getElementById('aa').value;
    ids_array = ids.split(',');
    for(var i=0; i<ids_array.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i])) {
            (function(i) {
                callAjax("<?php echo baseurl . 'notification.php';?>?users_id=" + ids_array[i], function(response){
                    document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i]).innerHTML = response;
                });
            }(i));
        }
    }
}

function callAjax(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: yes, I tried your answer, but I always in php file received last value of my array...

Comment: I believe now I see another problem: you can't fire multiple requests in a loop with that code, you need multiple XMLHttpRequest instances. Which brings me to: can't you get rid of the whole loop and fire a single request, passing all the IDs at once, and responding with all the info you need?

Comment: I have a table, the first column should be notification about new messages (messages), and the second is the full name of the user. So I check with the elements of the array, if the user has a new message appears notification about it.

Comment: @vazgen Okay, I was suggesting a different approach, but nevermind. See my update, I hope the code I just added works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your ids_array[i] variable is not correctly defined in xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(), 
because "i" variable redefines with every FOR cycle iteration.

So all code should be:

```
var ids = document.getElementById('aa').value;
var ids_array = ids.split(',');

for (var i=0; i<ids_array.length; i++)
{
  if (document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i])) {
    // For every iteration, create a closure that 
    // stores the "i" variable multiple times with different values in the closure.
    // Also create an xmlhttp Object for each request.
    var closure = function()
    {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i]).innerHTML = result;
          // After this function executes, it and any closures it has will be
          // available for garbage collection.
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo baseurl . 'notification.php';?>?users_id=" + ids_array[i], true);
      xmlhttp.send();

      // This code ends, but xmlhttp objects wait for onreadystatechange event.
    }
  }
}
```

I suggest you to read more about closures.

Comment: Your `i` in the callback will always be `ids_array.length + 1`. You need to include another scope; like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18017646/444991

Comment: I deleted break and after your code I add this
xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo baseurl . 'notification.php';?>?users_id="+ids_array[i],true);
xmlhttp.send();
Is it correct ?

Comment: @Matt for(var i in ids_array) iterates through all elements in ids_array (i.e. 0,1,2,3), but of course it will iterate through "ids_array.length" element so it looks like 0,1,2,3,length

Comment: You can't move the loop to the callback, `i` is also being used to construct the URL in `xmlhttp.open()`

Comment: @ Nikolay Gromov  ReferenceError: i is not defined. Probably I should insert last 2 lines in cycle, but I'm not sure..

Comment: @vazgen No, or your ajax calls will never fire. Did you try my answer?

Comment: @vazgen I did final changes to my answer. You need to run this code when window.onload fires. You can put it into something like window.onload=function(){/*example code*/}

Comment: @ Nikolay Gromov. I tried this, but probably it doesn't works correctly, for example, in my php file if I will type only <?php echo "aaaa";?> result doesn't displayed.

Comment: @vazgen Its too much for this question, i need more info to help you. We can communicate anywhere else to solve this problem. Maybe in messenger.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any details about where the browser was reporting the problem (line of code), but my guess would be this:

```
var ids = document.getElementById('aa').value;
```

The most likely culprit is that you have no element with an id (`id="aa"`) of `aa`. Either that or you did something bizarre like this:

`document = ...`

somewhere in your code. That it's *`null`* rather than `undefined` is kind of weird.

Comment: OP mentioned, that the first code block is ok, but the error appear with the second code block on the line `document.getElementById('a' + ids_array[i]).innerHTML=xmlhttp.response;`